# How to use Coldfusion toScript when refreshing a page in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-mobile, coldfusion

I'm having a multi-language site and need to pass error messages in different languages to the browser for client-side form validation.

Right now I'm using a error.cfc, which contains:

```
 <cfcomponent displayname="errorMsg" hint="create error msgs">  
      <cffunction name="createErrMsgsLog" output="false" returntype="string">               

           <cfset var allErrMsgs=ArrayNew(2)>
           <cfquery datasource="db" name="texte" cachedWithin="#Session.globalCache#">
                ... query db for snippets and text blocks ...
           </cfquery>
           <cfoutput query="texte"><cfset "#trim(snippet)#" = "#trim(text)#"></cfoutput>
           <cfscript>
                allErrMsgs[1][1] = "comp";
                allErrMsgs[1][2] = tx_validate_comp;
                ...
           </cfscript>
           <cfset Session.errMsgs = serializeJSON(allErrMsgs)>
           <cfreturn Session.errMsgs> 
      </cffunction>
 </cfcomponent>
```

So I'm grabbing all texts, fill an array, which is serialized and returned as a string.

The cfc is called inside application.cfc

```
 <cffunction name="onSessionStart" returnType="boolean" output="false" hint="session initalizer">
      ...
      <cfinvoke component="services.errorMsg" method="createErrMsgsLog" returnvariable="errMsgs"></cfinvoke>
      <cfset Session.errMsgs = errMsgs>
      ...
 </cffunction>
```

And on every page I'm including it like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">var #toScript(Session.errMsgs, "errorLog")#</script>
```

I'm not sure why I'm ending up with **errorLog is undefined** sometimes, but it happens occassionaly when I'm refreshing a page or when I enter a page URL manually inside my application (go from page ABC to page DEF).

I'm using Jquery Mobile, so when the Session inits and the first page loads, the errorLog is rendered once into the first page. Since all subsequent pages are pulled in/removed from this page, the initial errorLog is always active. I guess when manually changing the URL, I'm loosing the first page errorLog, because I'm loading a new page, but I don't understand why the new page does not get "it's own" errorLog or why it's undefined all of a sudden.

**Question:**
Any idea how I can make sure errorLog is defined = how can I ensure the errorMessages gets created in Coldfusion?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**
Ok. I have added a check in Coldfusion, so in case the Session variables is undefined, I'm recreating it. So far however, it is always there. It seems to only happen when I manually change the URL and go to another page. I can reproduce in IE8. Strangely, when I check the IE8 debugger, errorLog is there, but I'm still getting an error telling me it's undefined...

**EDIT:**
I have moved the cfinvoke to on request handler inside the application.cfc.

```
    <cfif len( Session.errMsgs ) EQ 0>
        <cfinvoke component="services.errorMsg" method="createErrMsgsLog" returnvariable="errMsgs"></cfinvoke>
        <cfset Session.errMsgs = errMsgs> 
    </cfif>
```

The Coldfusion part seems to work correctly, because I'm only ending up inside the if-statement when the application fires up. Afterwards errMsgs are defined, but the problem remains... Frustrating.

**EDIT**:
Another cause could be my JSON string. I'm setting it like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">var #toScript(Session.errMsgs, "errorLog")#; alert(errorLog);</script>
```

The alert alerts it allright, but if I try to grab it later on like so:

```
 err = jQuery.parseJSON(errorLog);
```

I'm getting NULL. My JSON looks like this (**valid, alerting Session.errMsgs**)

```
 [["firma","Bitte Firmennamen eingeben!"],["firma_re","Bitte Firmennamen eingeben!"],...
```

or this (invalid, outputting with toScript):

```
 "[[\"firma\",\"Bitte Firmennamen eingeben!\"],[\"firma_re\",\.... (invalid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue. I'm using RequireJS and I had the call to initiliaze requireJS above the snippet, which entered the variable onto the page. While this seems to work on the first page, on subsequent page, requireJS seems much faster in re-parsing js files, so the file looking for *errorLog* was parsed before the variable was set on the page. Moving requireJS init to after setting errorLog seems to solve the problem.... some search...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if this is it, but I noticed a couple of errors:

```
<cfif len( Session.errMsgs ) EQ 0>
    <cfinvoke component="services.errorMsg" method="createErrMsgsLog" returnvariable="errMsgs"></cfinvoke>
    <cfset Session.errMsgs = errMsgs> 
</cfif>
```

should be:

```
<cfif arrayLen( Session.errMsgs ) EQ 0>
    <cfinvoke component="services.error" method="createErrMsgsLog" returnvariable="errMsgs"></cfinvoke>
    <cfset Session.errMsgs = errMsgs> 
</cfif>
```

Session.errMsgs should be an array, so you use the arrayLen() function. Also, you call components by file name, not display name, so "services.error" instead of "services.errorMsg".

Also, I'd set the variable directly in the return from the component, to avoid any variable scope issues:

```
<cfinvoke component="services.error" method="createErrMsgsLog" returnvariable="SESSION.errMsgs"></cfinvoke>
```

Well, actually, I'd probably not use cfinvoke at all, but that's more of a style thing.

Comment: cool. Let me look into this. I'm also wondering if it's my JSON string and me trying to jQuery.parseJSON( errorLog ), which comes out as "NULL". I have just checked on jsonlint.com... json is valid. I will post another edit, 1 sec

Comment: re cfinvoke... I have my whole application done with invoke, so... I'm sticking with it while I'm using CF8. Read somewhere CF8 has trouble with createObject

Comment: Mh. Not it. Session.errMsgs is a string, because I'm serializeJSON(allErrMsgs) before returning. Using arrayLen produces an error.